# Line is too short - error in Revit API but works manually on Revit UI

Tags: revit-api

I am working on a task where I need to update some parameters in a loop for a pipe fitting model
but the issue is that I am getting the below UI when I commit the transaction.


[image]


The weird part is that,

1. I am adding parameters in a loop, and only one of 10 fails.
2. Also, the same row that failed programmatically works when I try with it in the Revit UI manually.

Since the code only fails for 1 row, I am clear that the code is correct.

```
using (Transaction tr = new Transaction(famDoc))
{
    tr.Start("add data");
    DN = "400";
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DN))
    {
         double dn = Convert.ToDouble(DN);
         dn = UnitUtils.ConvertToInternalUnits(dn, DisplayUnitType.DUT_MILLIMETERS);
         Parameters.SetParameterFamily(famManager, famDoc, "GEOMETRY", ParameterType.Length, false, "DN", dn);
    }
    tr.Commit();
}
```

Also, I came across this link
[https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Revit-error-Line-is-too-short.html][2]

But I did not understand the solution in my context.
Can someone help me with the solution

These are the values of the loop

I also added the result of the UnitUtils.ConvertToInternalUnits(dn, DisplayUnitType.DUT_MILLIMETERS)

1. DN = 300 // 0.98425, DN_AB = 100 // 0.3250
2. DN = 300 // 0.98425, DN_AB = 150 // 0.4921
3. DN = 300 // 0.98425, DN_AB = 200 // 0.6561
4. DN = 300 // 0.98425, DN_AB = 250 // 0.82020
5. DN = 300 // 0.98425, DN_AB = 300 // 0.98425
6. DN = 350 // 1.14829, DN_AB = 350 // 1.14829 // This fails

Thank you in advance

Comment: are all the 10 lines of the same length?

Comment: no, they are all different

Comment: Then make sure that this specific line is longer than 0.793 mm or 1/32", That is the constraint

Comment: @MostafaTarekYassien: Thank you for your reply. I have updated my question to add the rows that passed and that which failed. Can you point of the error in the values, because the one longer fails

Comment: @MostafaTarekYassien: I am not able to recreate this issue from Revit UI

Comment: I have tried to search for the problem , no luck, i guess we will just wait for the community

Comment: oh ok, Thank you @MostafaTarekYassien for your help